# Nested json string with variables in php

Tags: php, json, variables, quotes

I will not lie to you guys: i hate nested Arrays.

So instead of my [working] code below

```
$query_array = Array(
    "fields" => Array ("timestamp", "user.raw", "mailbox", "verb", "backend"),
    "size"   => 1,
    "sort"   => Array (Array ("@timestamp" => Array ("order" => $varOrder))),
    "query"  => Array (
        "bool" => Array (
            "must" => Array (
                Array ("match" => Array ("verb"    => "open")),
                Array ("term"  => Array ($varField => $varValue))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I want to use the [non working] code below

```
$query_json_string = '{
    "fields" : [ "timestamp", "user.raw", "mailbox", "verb", "backend" ],
    "size"   : 1,
    "sort"   : [ { "@timestamp" : { "order" : $varOrder } } ],
    "query"  : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "match" : { "verb"    : "open" } },
                { "term"  : { $varField : $varValue } }
            ]
        }
    }
}';
```

So much easier to maintain...

But inside the single quotes the variables `varOrder`, `varField` and `varValue` are never expanded (i believe).

How can i use variables inside this nice and clean json string?

Comment: As of [php 5.4](https://php.net/manual/migration54.new-features.php) you can use a short syntax to create an array (just as in js) `["timestamp"] ...`. So the only difference would be `=>` instead of `:`. Really, just don't even start working around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you're simply *not happy* with php's array syntax. If that's the case, then don't use the *old* syntax. Instead use simple square brackets, which are available since version 5.4.

Doing so, your final code could be:

```
$query = [
    "fields" => ["timestamp", "user.raw", "mailbox", "verb", "backend"],
    "size"   => 1,
    "sort"   => [["@timestamp" => ["order" => $varOrder]]],
    "query"  => [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
                ["match" => ["verb"    => "open"]],
                ["term"  => [$varField => $varValue]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Which issn't far off your desired syntax. The only difference being `=>` instead of `:`. But with the added benefit of not needing to declare *objects* with `{}`.

Comment: i think he's trying to do the opposite. use json_decode and then just put JSON inside. that way you can avoid the PHP syntax all together

Comment: Well let's see what he/she has to say. As you said on your question, all in all the whole question is a bit pointless.

Comment: @Pamblam If this is really just a syntax question, then you're probably right that `json_decode` would be the right thing to use, if one really were to use it for strange reasons as this.

Comment: thanks for your help. i upvoted your answer, but someone downvoted it (that's why the zero). but i marked it as accepted.

Comment: @RASG That's not a problem really, it's just stackoverlow. Someone simply didn't like it, who probably knows why. ;) If it helped you, all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is basically Javascript's version of a associative array.

```
$query_array = Array(
    "fields" => Array ("timestamp", "user.raw", "mailbox", "verb", "backend"),
    "size"   => 1,
    "sort"   => Array (Array ("@timestamp" => Array ("order" => $varOrder))),
    "query"  => Array (
        "bool" => Array (
            "must" => Array (
                Array ("match" => Array ("verb"    => "open")),
                Array ("term"  => Array ($varField => $varValue))
            )
        )
    )
);

$query_json_string = json_encode($query_array);
```

But if you have a problem with that, heredoc syntax should work for you..

```
$query_json_string = <<<JSON
{
    "fields" : [ "timestamp", "user.raw", "mailbox", "verb", "backend" ],
    "size"   : 1,
    "sort"   : [ { "@timestamp" : { "order" : $varOrder } } ],
    "query"  : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "match" : { "verb"    : "open" } },
                { "term"  : { $varField : $varValue } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
JSON;

// if you wanted PHP array,
$query_array = json_decode($query_json_string, true);
```

Comment: a professional chef would never say they hate onions. onions are an essential part of many recipes, just like a professional programmer would never say they hate something as fundamental as multidimensional arrays.... anyway I gave you the answer so how bout giving me some credit?

Comment: Interpolating the variables this way is a sure way to not get valid json-strings. For example `$varField` would actually need to include the double-quotes to make a valid string. Who knows what `$varValue` is holding.

Comment: depends what's in the variables. if the values are numbers it's fine otherwise just need to put quotes in there. also, it's unclear whether you want json or an PHP array..

Comment: That's what I'm saying. What's the benefit of controlling whether each and every value would *fit in*, when there's absolutely no need to do this?

Comment: there's no benefit to what he's trying to do in the first place. i'm just answering the question.

Comment: @RASG It may be your code, but it's the language's syntax you're using. If it's not in the syntax then fighting it will just give you trouble. That said, and as you can see by our comments, it's still not clear what you're actually asking. So please extend your question to make it clearer.

Comment: yea, it may seem easier right now but in the long run it's going to be much easier to just get comfortable with the syntax.

Comment: @RASG That's fine then, I simply wasn't sure. But please take our advice and don't fight the language's syntax. Just deal with it.

Comment: @Pamblam apart from indentation, your solution works. upvoted. thanks.

Comment: @RASG - When you use heredocs, the closing `JSON;` must not be indented. It has to be all the way up against the margin or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the from single to double quotes and escape your double qoutes

```
$query_json_string = "{
    \"fields\" : [ \"timestamp\", \"user.raw\", \"mailbox\", \"verb\",     \"backend\" ],
    \"size\"   : 1,
    \"sort\"   : [ { \"@timestamp\" : { \"order\" : $varOrder } } ],
    \"query\"  : {
        \"bool\": {
            \"must\": [
                { \"match\" : { \"verb\"    : \"open\" } },
                { \"term\"  : { $varField : $varValue } }
            ]
        }
    }
}";
```